# How can I switch contents of lists?

Tags: python

I have two lists, a and b.
I want to reassign the content of a into b and the content of b into a.

or in other words, after running a few operations with two lists, I want to switch the names of the lists. so that the list that was named a would now be named b, and the list that was named b would now be named a.

this way is obviously wrong:
a=b
b=a
(because they are both b now)

so, is there a right way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

python lets you do that as follows:

```
a, b = b, a
```

#### Example

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
a, b = b, a

>>> print a
[4,5,6]

>>> print b
[1,2,3]
```

This is because the expression on the right hand side is evaluated first and *then* assigned to variables on the left.

Comment: it doesn't change lists, only swaps name binding.

Comment: @m.wasowski can you explain the difference?

Comment: I am writing example, give me 3 minutes

Comment: @sshashank124 can you tell me how it works, or what this operation is called?

Comment: @pyni, There really isn't a "term" for it. I guess it would be variable swapping or variable switching

Comment: @pyni It's called tuple unpacking. When a tuple appears on the left-hand side of an assignment, the iterable on the right is "unpacked", and each element is assigned to its counterpart on the left. (The name isn't great, because the RHS can be any iterable and the LHS can be a list or tuple, as long as it contains valid l-values. Consider this monstrosity, `[(c,d), e] = ([7,8], 9)`, which correctly assigns values to `c`, `d`, and `e`.

Comment: It's called assignment. It's important to note that the `b, a` is an expression that results in an unnamed tuple comprised of the two lists being created. Each member of this tuple is then assigned to names `a` and `b` given on the righthand side.

Comment: @pyni I prepared answer with two approaches, that may help you see what I've meant.

Answer (score 1):

This might be not necessary for you, but good to remember that:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]

c = a # now 'c' points to the same list as 'a'
a[0] = 0 # let's change the first element
print a
# [0, 2, 3]
print c

# now let's use multiple assigment:
a, b = b, a
print a
# [3, 4, 5]
print c
# [0, 2, 3]

# list didn't change, but 'a' now point do different list
# but 'c' still point to the same, unchanged list, the one
# that is now referenced by 'b'
```

Above solution is fast and usually the best. But if you have the same list (or other mutable data structure) referenced by other names, you may swap contents of list instead:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]

c = a 
a[0] = 0 

a[:], b[:] = b[:], a[:] # now we actually swap contents

# 'a' and 'c' still point to the same list,
# but values are from 'b' list
print a 
# [3, 4, 5]
print b
# [0, 2, 3]
print c
# [3, 4, 5]
```